# array to string php

Tags: php, arrays

Hy every one I have this problem with an array I start like this...

```
$name =  array($_POST['names']);
$nameId = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM types WHERE find_in_set (name, '$name')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $nameId[] = array('ids' => $row['id'] );

    }
```

which gives me arrays like this..

$name:

```
array('0'=>'name1,name2,name3')
```

$names:

```
array('0'=>array('ids'=>'61'), '1'=>array('ids'=>'6'), '2'=>array('ids'=>'1'))
```

how can I bring this in an string/form like this..

```
array('0'=>'61,6,1')
```

The idea is to save the ids to the Database.

Or is the a better more efficent way to get names from a form compare them with a database and get the ids back to save them to the Database?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$name =  array(name1,name2,name3);
$nameId = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM types WHERE find_in_set (name, '$name')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
//below line changed
    $nameId[] =  $row['id'] ;

}
 $string = implode(',',$nameId);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your assignment to this:

```
$nameId[] = $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$array  = array(0=>array(0=>'61'),1=>array(0=>'6'),2=>array(0=>'1'));
$result = implode(",",call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array));
```

Please note : Here all are numeric keys, so change your code to :

`$nameId[] = array($row['id'] );` , remove key `'ids'` from here

Output :

```
61,6,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats what I think

```
$nameId[] = $row['id'];
$stringId = implode(',',$name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following function that will loop through array and find ids key and merge it into other array and after that when you calling this function it will impload it.

```
function CustomFindJoinArray( $needly, $array )
{
    $results = array();
    foreach ( $array as $key => $value )
    {
        if ( is_array( $value ) )
        {
            $results = array_merge($results, foo( $needly, $value ));
        }
        else if ( $key == $needly )
        {
            $results[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
echo implode( ",", CustomFindJoinArray( "ids", $your_array ) );
```

where `$your_array` will be `array('0'=>array('ids'=>'61'), '1'=>array('ids'=>'6'), '2'=>array('ids'=>'1'))`

**OR More simple**

```
foreach ($your_array as $key => $ids) {
    $newArray[] = $array[$key]["ids"];
}

$string = implode(',', $newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = array();
foreach($nameId as $curr) {
  $ids[] = $curr['ids'];
}
$str = "(".implode(",",$ids).")";
```